# How do I get my API client to post to my company page?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

We created an app on LinkedIn for our business page through my profile (as an admin for the page). We have the client ID, client secret and all other relevant information for posting. We are able to post to my page by php api client, but not the company page.

We are using the following API client to post content to our business page on LinkedIn: https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client

We set the following scopes:

```
'r_liteprofile','w_member_social', 'w_share','rw_organization_admin',
```

We retrieve the profile with this: $profile = $client->get('me');

We are trying to get the company's information with this:

```
$companyInfo = $client->get('organizationAcls',['q' => 'roleAssignee']);
```

This results in the following error: Not enough permissions to access: GET-roleAssignee /organizationAcls

Please advise.

Comment: Have you tried the [Share content on a LinkedIn business page](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client#share-content-on-a-linkedin-business-page) example?

Comment: Also [this discussion on Github](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client/issues/31) could be helpful